# UISegmentedControll not setting correct image

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to set a custom image for each segment control index in my `UISegmentedControll`

I am setting the image like so:

```
UIImage *selectAll = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Select All Active"];
[selectAll imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

[self.segmentedControl setImage:selectAll forSegmentAtIndex:0];
```

However I just get a white space in the segment index and the image doesn't show correctly.

Is there a different way to do this?

I am building the app for iOS7 only.

**Edit**

Here is what it looks like with image set in IB or Code:

[image]

Comment: Check You `selectAll` using
    `if (selectAll == nil) {  NSLog(@"selectAll Image nil");   }`

Comment: I've updated the question - please see the image I am getting

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your image does not exists, are your sure it is named 'Select All Active.png'? I suggest you rename it to test.png first to see if it works.

Comment: Yup, tested the image - it definitely exists. I did what you said and what I meant by white space is that I can see a UiImage outline in the index 0 - but its like a blue tint colour.

Comment: What you can try is creating a segmented control via the interface builder in xCode, and play with the various settings to see if you can improve the alignment and cover?

Answer (score 0):

I think Your `UIImage` object is `nil` So check is using.

```
UIImage *selectAll = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Select All Active"];
if (selectAll == nil) {
    NSLog(@"nil");
}
```

If not `nil` you can try using

```
UIImage *selectAll;
if ([UIImage instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(imageWithRenderingMode:)]) {
    selectAll = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Select All Active"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
}else {
    selectAll = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Select All Active"];
}
self.segmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.segmentedControl setImage:selectAll forSegmentAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried that and image definitely there - updated the question with a screen shot of the image.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are seeing is the divider of the `UISegmentedControl`. You need to set an image for the divider as well..